# Is MBP Pro 15'' Retina fan noise reduced noticeably?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Is there really noticeable reduction of noise from fans in new MBP Pro 15" Retina compared to original MBP Pro 15"? I'm curious if the asymmetrical blades configuration of fans really makes that significant difference which Apple is stating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have one, and it make a big difference. It's also a less unpleasant sound. I have to get the machine running pretty hot before I notice the fans at all. On my last machine, I would hear the fans all the time (granted, mine was a 13'', but several of my coworkers have 15'' and I hear their fans more than mine).

Comment: Maybe I have a lemon, but when the fans run they are just as loud as my previous 2010 15" MacBookPro. It does seem to take more use before the fans run, although compiling my app does it every time.

Comment: You should check out that compilation and see how much CPU it uses. A big spike in CPU usage will result in a spike in temperature. I use istat pro to monitor temperatures in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

They're in the new MacBook Air aswell

Comment: Really? That's interesting. Apple didn't mention it neither in keynote nor on the website. And then it would be logical to put the same fans in the original updated MBP Pro.